# Outlook 2007 Bitness

Tags: outlook-2007, email-headers

I need to get the bitness of Outlook, in 2010 it is stored in a ReqistryKey named Bitness under the path

64bit Windows:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Bitness
32bit Windows:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Bitness

In 2007 these Keys doesn't exist, and so I retrieve a null reference exception.

My Question is, how can I get the bitness in Outlook 2007? I need to set header, so I have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook 2007 does not have a 64-bit version.  If it's being used then it is the 32-bit version.

Comment: Thats really easy ^^ Thanks :)